# While Loop Not Working In Function For P5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am experienced in python but completely new to java. I am using p5 and want to set up a simple function that, depending on what number the user inputs, it draws that many circles. I'm not sure why it is not working.

```
var numProton;

function setup() {
  numProton = createInput();
  numProton.changed(nucleus);
  createCanvas(600, 500);
  background(255);  
}

function draw() {
    noStroke()
    textSize(15);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    text('^ # of Protons', 25, 30);
    text('^ # of Neutrons', 150, 30);
    text('^ # of Electrons', 275, 30);
}

function nucleus() {
    var i = 0;
    while(i <= numProton.value) {
        ellipse(300, 250, 10);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Probably a very simple error but I appreciate the help none the less.

Comment: What exactly is happening right now? Does it draw any circles at all?

Comment: `console.log(+numProton.value)` - what is the output in the developer tools console?

Comment: Where is nucleus being called from? The function draw will be called over and over in p5.js so if you arn't calling nucleus from there, that function won't be executed. Put a console.log('test') in nucleus to see if it is being called at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a `for` loop, it has the same exact purpose:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= numProton.value; i++) {
    ellipse(300, 250, 10);
}
```

Comment: if the while loop doesn't work, why would a for loop?

Comment: @JaromandaX What if the problem is with the `while` loop? In JavaScript, things like this have happened to me for weird reasons, where even if I copy and paste from the Documentation, it just refuses to work, so I look for another way!

Comment: The logic is identical. If you can show such a simple for loop working where a equivalent while loop fails I'll be impressed

Comment: `things like this have happened to me for weird reasons` - I take it you can't recall any of them?

Comment: @JaromandaX No, it's that I just never found out, I fixed the problem using a workaround. It's happened to me a couple of times.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that `numProton.value()` is supposed to be a function call with `()`?

See here [p5.js/changed](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/changed)